# pass data from a python application to a running c++ application

Tags: c++, python

I coded to applications one in python the other one in c++. In the middle of the python app I need to run the c++ app pass some input to it and receive the output. I already know that I can call the c++ app from python using subprocess but since that c++ app has to do some initial calculations each time it is called it makes my program really slow. So what I was looking for is this:

put my c++ app in an infinite while loop and keep it running. Then in my python app whenever I need a call to the c++ app just pass the data and get the output. This way i can avoid repeating the initial state every time I need to make this call.

Is there anyway to do this? Like writing another application that controls all of these. Also there can be multiple instances of the python app running but I want to have just one of the c++ app running since it takes a lot of memory

Comment: sorry I tried to make it more clear. Please point out any part that's still vague. Thank you

Comment: Some sample code would help make this answerable. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I tried using boost to wrap the c++ code in python but that's still has the problem of doing the initial computation multiple times.

Comment: Research IPC (interprocess communication).

Answer (score 3):

Using subprocess.Popen you can open a process and keep it open, use the stdin and stdout to communicate with it. When you open the process use:  stdout=subprocess.PIPE,  stdin=subprocess.PIPE .
You can then write to process.stdin and read from process.stdout the output of the c++ program.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with boost python. Design a class that perform the initial computation in its constructor and a method to perform the computation. You wrap it and instantiate it from python once.

subprocess solution is possible too, as asafpr answered.

You also can set a XML-RPC server in the C++ app and call it from Python with with xmlrpclib module.